# Laravel - selectRaw count - IF NULL Set to zero

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on filtering my products, but i only seem to get products where there is actually views logged.

How can i set "IF NULL = 0" or even do it smarter?

Here's my code:

```
if ($request->sort == 'views') {
   $query->leftJoin('analytics', 'foreign_id', '=', 'ads.id');
   $query->selectRaw('ads.*, IFNULL(count(analytics.id),0) as views');
   $query->orderBy('views', "$sort_order");
}
```

My DB looks like this: 
id | ip |  foreign_id | foreign_type | updated_at | created_at

Right now i have one row in my DB, and the product with that id i the only one showing.

Thank your so much in advance.

Comment: Do you want to have only the items for which there is no null views ?

Comment: IF NULL = 0 , basically you want something like NOT IS NULL(analytics.id) ?

Comment: I want to get all my products even if they have 0 views, but since there is no rows on the left join, it just does not add the key "views" to my object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to group, then it worked perfectly.

```
if ($request->sort == 'views') {

    $query->leftJoin('analytics', 'foreign_id', '=', 'ads.id');
    $query->selectRaw('ads.*, count(analytics.id) as views');
    $query->orderBy('views', "$sort_order");
    $query->groupBy('ads.id');

}
```

Comment: Glad you solved it! Btw, you can mark yourself as correct answer! So next guy who lands on this question will have an easy time getting his answer :)

Comment: Thank you, i will do that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think [`COALESCE`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php) (assuming MySQL) is what you're looking for. Try this:

```
if ($request->sort == 'views') {
   $query->leftJoin('analytics', 'foreign_id', '=', 'ads.id');
   $query->selectRaw('ads.*, COALESCE(count(analytics.id),0) as views');
   $query->orderBy('views', "$sort_order");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, this makes no difference for me, it gets the same one products that has a row in my analytics table. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($request->sort == 'views') {
   $query->leftJoin('analytics', 'foreign_id', '=', 'ads.id');
   $query->whereNotNull('analytics');
   $query->selectRaw('ads.*, analytics.id as views');
   $query->orderBy('views', "$sort_order");
}
```

I leave this one as a suggestion at the moment - I am pretty sure it will not work as you wish, but it just gives some directions

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it does the opposite, which is why im confused. I want to left join views regardless of how many row exists, even if no rows exists, then it should just be 0 on the count i think,